# WindwosForms entre áreas de trabalhos windows 10

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-10

Tenho uma aplicação em Windows Forms e várias áreas de trabalho e preciso abrir uma janela em todos estas áreas, já busquei na internet e encontrei https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31801402/api-for-windows-10-virtual-desktops e
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32416843/altering-win10-virtual-desktop-behavior/32417530#32417530 porém em nenhum explica como abrir uma Form em todas as áreas de trabalho, Como faço para abrir uma janela em cada área de trabalho aberta?

OBS:

- É para abrir uma nova Form em cada Área de trabalho.

Comment: é um form, que ocupa todas as áreas de trabalho, com vários monitores, ou vários forms, um para cada área de trabalho ? Ou ainda, você usa aqueles software que criam várias áreas de trabalho no mesmo monitor, semelhante ao linux ?

Comment: Modifiquei a pergunta, dá uma olhada @RovannLinhalis

Comment: dá uma olhada nessa publicação: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33548454/perisistant-window-across-multiple-windows-10-virtual-desktops

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Eu não consegui só compreender o que ela quiz dizer com 'The Dispatcher.Invoke is necessary because the event is on a different thread then the UI one, so the call must be marshaled to the UI thread.'

Comment: o evento disparado está em uma thread diferente da interface do usuário, por isso a necessidade do método Invoke